# a term expected error when trying to insert typescript element in the styling

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, styling

In my ts file I have elements that I use in the html file. In this example I use element.color (value = #3b5998) and element.name (value = Facebook). When putting the values like below the icon one works but the color is not. The code looks like this:

`<fa  style="color: {{element.color}};" name="{{element.icon}} fa-3x"></fa>`

After the color: there is a red line saying, "a term expected". But I don't know what to change. I know it's a dump error but i'm stuck.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZolVM.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To bind to a style there are two ways:

Using [`style binding`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#style-binding)

```
<fa [style.color]="element.color" [name]="element.icon + ' fa-3x'"></fa>
```

or by using the [`NgStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) directive

```
<fa [ngStyle]="{ color: element.color }" [name]="element.icon + 'fa-3x'"></fa>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction! Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the quotation marks (") between the attributes of the tag (fa). You need to put them only at the beginning and at the end of the record of all attributes